# Can't login my App using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Android Programming and working as an intern developer.

I'm currently working on Firebase Authentication, trying to do a login screen.

I added a user in Firebase. When I keep email or pw, program correctly displays error saying "Enter both email and pw" (in my language). But when I click button, nothing happens. Literally nothing.

package com.example.jalea.requestingform;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText edt_email,edt_sifre;
    Button bt_giris;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edt_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_mail);
        edt_sifre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_sifre);
        bt_giris = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_giris);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() !=null){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,RequestActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else{
                    Log.w("1 : ", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
            }
        };
        bt_giris.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SignIn();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(authStateListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
        }
    }
    public void SignIn(){
        String email = edt_email.getText().toString();
        String sifre = edt_sifre.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(sifre)){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Kullanıcı adı veya şifre alanı boş",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,sifre).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Auth. Problem",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }



    }
}
```

This is xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.jalea.requestingform.MainActivity"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="e-mail"
        android:id="@+id/et_mail"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="sifre"
        android:id="@+id/et_sifre"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Giriş"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_giris"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I added a user in Firebase. When i keep email or pw, program correctly displays error saying "Enter both email and pw" (in my language). But when i click button nothing happens. Literally,nothing.

> 06-19 05:16:37.143 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform I/art:
>   Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>           06-19 05:16:37.144 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
>           06-19 05:16:37.729 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
>   /data/app/com.example.jalea.requestingform-2/lib/x86
>           06-19 05:16:38.415 2453-2475/com.example.jalea.requestingform W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for
>   com.google.firebase.auth not found.
>           06-19 05:16:38.440 2453-2475/com.example.jalea.requestingform W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
>           06-19 05:16:38.484 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform W/InstanceID/Rpc: Failed to resolve REGISTER intent, falling back
>           06-19 05:16:38.492 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform W/InstanceID/Rpc: Both Google Play Services and legacy GSF package are
>   missing
>           06-19 05:16:38.493 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked.
>   Skipping initialization.
>           06-19 05:16:38.637 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 10084
>           06-19 05:16:38.637 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA
>   VERBOSE
>           06-19 05:16:38.637 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
>           06-19 05:16:38.637 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform D/FA: AppMeasurement singleton hash: 23426705
>           06-19 05:16:38.733 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Collection enabled
>           06-19 05:16:38.740 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: App package, google app id: com.example.jalea.requestingform,
>   1:274099860490:android:14b27427a401eb21
>           06-19 05:16:38.740 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
>                                                                                 adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app
>   com.example.jalea.requestingform
>           06-19 05:16:38.902 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
>           06-19 05:16:38.907 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
>           06-19 05:16:38.909 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
>           06-19 05:16:38.946 2453-2479/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Using local app measurement service
>           06-19 05:16:39.066 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform W/art: Before Android 4.1, method
>   android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter
>   android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter,
>   android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)
>   would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
>           06-19 05:16:39.088 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: onActivityCreated
>           06-19 05:16:39.273 2453-2479/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Using local app measurement service
>           06-19 05:16:39.273 2453-2479/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>           06-19 05:16:39.276 2453-2479/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1695486
>   [ 06-19 05:16:39.360  2453: 2453 D/         ]
>   HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe24237c0, tid
>   2453
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    [ 06-19 05:16:39.373  2453: 2453 W/         ]
>   Process pipe failed
>           06-19 05:16:39.383 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Local AppMeasurementService is starting up
>           06-19 05:16:39.391 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform W/1 :: onAuthStateChanged:signed_out
>           06-19 05:16:39.532 2453-2482/com.example.jalea.requestingform D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
>           06-19 05:16:39.533 2453-2482/com.example.jalea.requestingform E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen
>   failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
>           06-19 05:16:39.538 2453-2482/com.example.jalea.requestingform D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
>           06-19 05:16:39.544 2453-2482/com.example.jalea.requestingform D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
>           06-19 05:16:39.576 2453-2482/com.example.jalea.requestingform D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
>           06-19 05:16:39.624 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Bound to IMeasurementService interface
>           06-19 05:16:39.627 2453-2479/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Connected to service
>           06-19 05:16:39.628 2453-2479/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
>           06-19 05:16:39.821 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int
>   android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int,
>   boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method
>   in android.widget.ListView
>   06-19 05:16:39.901  2453: 2482 D/         ]
>                                                                                HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe2423d40, tid
>   2482
>           06-19 05:16:39.904 2453-2479/com.example.jalea.requestingform I/FA: This instance being marked as an uploader
>           06-19 05:16:39.947 2453-2479/com.example.jalea.requestingform D/FA: Unable to get advertising id: java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info.getId()'
>   on a null object reference:
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatl.zzfK(Unknown Source)
>           06-19 05:16:39.951 2453-2482/com.example.jalea.requestingform I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>           06-19 05:16:39.952 2453-2482/com.example.jalea.requestingform D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
>           06-19 05:16:40.080 2453-2482/com.example.jalea.requestingform E/EGL_emulation: tid 2482: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009
>   (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
>           06-19 05:16:40.080 2453-2482/com.example.jalea.requestingform W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface
>   0xf347c320, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
>           06-19 05:16:40.891 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform I/Choreographer: Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too
>   much work on its main thread.
>           06-19 05:16:44.904 2453-2479/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
>           06-19 05:16:44.909 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: onUnbind called for intent. action:
>   com.google.android.gms.measurement.START
>           06-19 05:16:44.920 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Local AppMeasurementService is shutting down
>           06-19 05:16:49.286 2453-2479/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Session started, time: 1705500
>           06-19 05:16:49.295 2453-2479/com.example.jalea.requestingform I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
>           06-19 05:16:49.307 2453-2479/com.example.jalea.requestingform D/FA: Logging event (FE): _s, Bundle[{_o=auto, _sc=MainActivity,
>   _si=-6096220152962165033}]
>           06-19 05:16:49.395 2453-2479/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Using local app measurement service
>           06-19 05:16:49.414 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Local AppMeasurementService is starting up
>           06-19 05:16:49.417 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Bound to IMeasurementService interface
>           06-19 05:16:49.420 2453-2479/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Connected to service
>           06-19 05:16:49.420 2453-2479/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
>           06-19 05:16:49.512 2453-2479/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Logging event:
>   origin=auto,name=_s,params=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=108]
>           06-19 05:16:49.584 2453-2479/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Saving event, name, data size: _s, 58
>           06-19 05:16:49.588 2453-2479/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Event recorded: Event{appId='com.example.jalea.requestingform',
>   name='_s', params=Bundle[{_o=auto, _sc=MainActivity,
>   _si=-6096220152962165033}]}
>           06-19 05:16:49.660 2453-2479/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 2103350
>           06-19 05:16:49.671 2453-2479/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Background event processing time, ms: 160
>           06-19 05:16:53.330 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive
>   InputConnection
>           06-19 05:16:54.519 2453-2479/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
>           06-19 05:16:54.524 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: onUnbind called for intent. action:
>   com.google.android.gms.measurement.START
>           06-19 05:16:54.534 2453-2453/com.example.jalea.requestingform V/FA: Local AppMeasurementService is shutting down
>           06-19 05:16:58.759 2453-2475/com.example.jalea.requestingform W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for
>   com.google.firebase.auth not found.
>           06-19 05:16:58.764 2453-2475/com.example.jalea.requestingform W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
>           06-19 05:17:00.113 2453-2475/com.example.jalea.requestingform W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for
>   com.google.firebase.auth not found.
>           06-19 05:17:00.116 2453-2475/com.example.jalea.requestingform W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.

Comment: is your password more than 6 characters ?

Comment: Yes,it's 8 characters.